# Read and display array nested values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have to display the tab values in a list with heading and subheading. I can read the object keys count but failed to get the values of each node and child values.

Please advise on how to retrieve the values and display in HTML

[image]

```js
var tab= {
  "a": {
    "one": [
      {
        "name": "xxx",
        "age": "10"
      } 
    ],
    "two": [
      {
        "name": "yxss",
        "age": "11"
      }
    ]
  },
  "b": {
    "one": [
      {
        "name": "ctr",
        "age": "11"
      },
      {
        "name": "cft",
        "age": "11"
      }
    ]
  },
  "c": {
    "two": [
      {
        "name": "cccc",
        "age": "11"
      }
    ]
  }
}

let count = Object.keys(tab).length;
console.log(count);
for (i =0; i < count ; i ++)
{ 
  console.log("<h1>"+tab[i]+"</h1>");
  let count1 = Object.values(tab[i]).length;
    for (j =0; j < count1 ; j++)
    { 
      console.log(tab[i][j]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put images. Put the code

Comment: you're accessing keys of tab wrongly, you're using integer index to access values of tab, which is not available

Comment: @CodeManiac is there any other alternative way to access keys of tab

Comment: `let count = Object.keys(tab)`, now instead of `tab[i]` in your loop do `count[i]`

Comment: @CodeManiac Yes that works ..i will loops other items in similar way. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it good for you?

```js
var tab= {
  "a": {
    "one": [
      {
        "name": "xxx",
        "age": "10"
      } 
    ],
    "two": [
      {
        "name": "yxss",
        "age": "11"
      }
    ]
  },
  "b": {
    "one": [
      {
        "name": "ctr",
        "age": "11"
      },
      {
        "name": "cft",
        "age": "11"
      }
    ]
  },
  "c": {
    "two": [
      {
        "name": "cccc",
        "age": "11"
      }
    ]
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  Object.keys(tab).forEach(function(k) {
    $('#result').append('<h1>' + k + '</h1>')
      Object.keys(tab[k]).forEach(function(kk) {
        $('#result').append('<ul id= "' + kk + '">' + kk + '</ul>')
        tab[k][kk].forEach(function(i) {
          $('#'+kk).append('<li>' + i.name  + '</li>')
        })
      })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var tab= {"a": {"one": [{"name": "xxx","age": "10"} ],"two": [{"name": "yxss","age": "11"}]},"b": {"one": [{"name": "ctr","age": "11"},{"name": "cft","age": "11"}]},"c": {"two": [{"name": "cccc","age": "11"}]}}

tab = Object.entries(tab).map(([key, value]) => `<ul><li>${key}
<ul>${Object.entries(value).map(([k, v]) => `<li>${k}
<ul>${v.map(obj => `<li>${obj.name}</li>`).join('')}</ul>
</li>`).join('')}</ul>
</li></ul>`).join('')
document.write(tab);
```

Comment: Much simplified. Thank you

Comment: can you please help me understand on the display of comma in between the list items and how to remove

Comment: it happened because I was converting the array to string, and when its do that, by default it's add comma between items. I has added a `.join('')` to make it converted to string without adding a comma. please take a look now